# SQL UPDATE fields on only the duplicate records, initial instance must not change

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

What is the best way to find and update duplicate records only from a table.  For instance, the below records are considered duplicates with only the ID making them unique.  I need to update records 2 and 3 active field to 0 instead of 1 and set the date to getdate(). I need the first instance of these duplicate (ID 1) to not be updated.  I have a table that has thousands of this scenario and need to deactivate the duplicate records.

Any ideas?

acct_plan table:

```
ID  act   plan   active   date   
1   123   blue   1        NULL    
2   123   blue   1        NULL  
3   123   blue   1        NULL
```

Thanks in advance for any help!  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use the following CTE for this type of problem:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ap.*,
             row_number() over (partition by act, plan, active, date
                                order by id
                               ) as seqnum
      from acct_plan
     )
update toupdate
    set date = getdate(),
        active = 0
    where seqnum > 1;
```

This is syntax that SQL Server supports, but doesn't generally work in other databases.

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  Question, in the update statement, I see that you indicated "toupdate" as the update table, should it be acct_plan since?  Isn't "toupdate" kind of a temp table?

Comment: No, @Montwill, the update target is correct. SQL Server understands that you mean to update `acct_plan` through the *alias* `toupdate`. Targeting the `acct_plan` table anew would require `JOIN`ing the `toupdate` table to it--a much more expensive--and needless--operation. CTEs and derived tables *can* be the target of an UPDATE, so long as you don't try to update a column that doesn't exist in the table, and the server can calculate a 1-to-1 correspondence for each row to be updated.

Comment: @Montwill . . . No.  This is a nice feature of SQL Server, where you can have updatable CTEs.  I need the sequence number here for the `where` clause and it is right there in the data.  The CTE is treated as an updatable view.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks for your smarts ErikE and Gordon! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
update t1 
set t1.active=0,
t1.date = GETDATE()
from acct_plan t1
where t1.ID NOT in (select MIN(t2.Id) from acct_plan t2
                    GROUP BY t2.act, t2.[plan], t2.active, t2.date);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f91a/1)

By the way, `plan` is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) in sql server 2005. Always a bad idea to use reserved keywords for object names...

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to @Gordon's query. Just to show you another way to accomplish it (SQL 2005 and up):

```
UPDATE A
SET
   A.active = 0,
   A.date = GetDate()
FROM
   (
      SELECT A.*, MinID = Min(A.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY A.act, A.[plan], A.date)
      FROM dbo.acct_plan A
      WHERE A.active = 1
   ) A
WHERE
   A.ID > A.MinID
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3729b/1)

I will also echo Raphaël Althaus that `plan` is a reserved keyword in SQL Server and should not be used for column names. You can see that my query had to enclose the word in square brackets in order to parse and run at all--not an ideal situation.

Comment: Gordon's solution updates a CTE, which I know is doable in SQL Server. Your solution updates a view. Does SQL Server actually push the update down to the underlying table?

Comment: A CTE is also a view! Try it!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
update acct_plan set active = 0, date = getdate()
where ID in 
(select ID FROM  acct_plan 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 (SELECT    MIN(ID) AS RowId, act, plan, active, date
                            FROM acct_plan
                            GROUP BY act, plan, active, date) 
                 AS KeepRows ON acct_plan.ID = KeepRows.RowId
WHERE (KeepRows.RowId IS NULL))
```

Comment: This is more convoluted than it needs to be